# A 110V air purifier comes with a 100-240V adapter

Tags: adapter

I have a 110V air purifier that comes with a 100-240V adapter. Can I still use the air purifier with power input 220-240V? Do I need a transformer or converter? Thank you.

Edit: I can’t find the attachment option :(. This is what it’s written on the adapter 100-240V. 50/60Hz. 0.8A Output is 24V and 1A

This is printed on the air purifier 110V/60Hz.

Does that mean I can use the air purifier anywhere in the world since the power adapter is 100-240V? Auto-switching?

Comment: you can plug the adapter into 240 V power outlet

Comment: Can you shoot us a photo of the data plate on the adapter?  Or at least, can you tell us the current range (in amps) if listed?

Comment: If the air purifier has 110V/60Hz on it, then you must only run it on 110V/60Hz. The adapter may be rated up to 240 V, but it will not convert that to 110 V. The adapter may have been included so that different shape 110 V sockets can be used.

Answer (score 2):

If the device has a 100-240V adapter, it's a **100-240V** device, **not** a 110V device. Or more likely it's a (some lower DC voltage you have not looked at - should be printed on the adapter, usually in tiny faint type) device with an adapter that is 100-240V

So, you should not need anything more than a way to plug its adapter in to use with 240VAC

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That’s the confusion. It’s stated as 110V device printed on the item but the adapter is 100-240V. Is the adapter also a converter or transformer? I’m really confused.

Comment: Pictures would help to clarify this.

Comment: @Ecnerwal It's almost certainly labelled as a 110V device because the **plug** that was supplied with the adaptor is a 110V plug.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If it's rated as 100-240V, you can plug into either 110 sockets or 220 sockets. A good example is laptop adapters. The only tricky part is IF it will fit into the physical holes. Then there are universal adapters as well.

Answer (score 0):

Usually items marked 100-240v are autoswitching, they react to the voltage supplied within the range. It is probably packaged as a 110v because that is the only cord it is intended to be packaged with. If it is marked 110v and the plug configuration doesn't match a standard receptacle then it was packed in the wrong box.